# grep expression for matching phone numbers

Tags: linux, grep

I need a regular expression that will match phone numbers that can be in the form `1-434-555-1212` or `434-555-1212` or `(434)555-1212` or `555-1212`.

I have gotten all the them except for the form starting with a 1.

```
grep -o '\([0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{4\}\)\|\(([0-9]\{3\})[0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{4\}\)\|\([0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{4\}\)\|\(1-[0-9]\{3\}\-[0-9]\{4\}\)'
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `-` in regular expressions, unless it's inside `[ ]`.

Comment: Put `\(1-\)?` at the beginning of the regexp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified this

```
  grep -o '
    \([0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}\)\|
    \(([0-9]\{3\})[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}\)\|
    \(\(1-\)?[0-9]\{3\}-[0-9]\{4\}\)' phones.txt

1-434-555-1212
434-555-1212
(434)555-1212
555-1212
```

Change your last condition to \(1-\)?
The '?' is for the optional character. You can get this done with just three conditional steps now. I removed the third one, and it still works. Also removed the escape sequences for hyphens.

Comment: Thats still not working for me. It wont pick up the leading 1